# Number of ways to chose 6 courses out of 15 (different) courses

Tags: combinatorics

We got 3 English courses, 6 Chinese courses, 6 Spanish courses.

Each course is different.

In how many was can we choose 6 courses such that we must chose atleast 1 course from each topic (English, Chinese, Spanish)

If possible, I would like to see a solution without the inclusion - exclusion principle.

edit : I got to $\frac{6*6*3}{3!}*\binom{12}{3}\;$ where $\frac{6*6*3}{3!}$ represents picking a course from each topic (we must choose atleast 1 from each topic), then dividing by the number of permutations. then we are left with 3 courses to choose from 12, so I multiplied by  $\binom{12}{3}\;$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @saulspatz I got to $\frac{6*6*3}{3!}*\binom{12}{3}$

Comment: Please edit the question to show how you got that.  I don't follow it at all.

Comment: @saulspatz done. sorry for that!

Comment: why avoid inclusion-exclusion?  This problem is a natural for that technique.

Comment: @lulu I want to see if there's a way by using "regular" combinatorics

Comment: Sure, just go case by case.  Suppose you have only one E course.  Then you need to have $5$ courses from the other two...easy to compute that case.  Now suppose you have exactly two E courses.  Similarly easy.  then do three $E$ courses.

Comment: $\frac {6*6*6}{3!}{12\choose 3}$ unfortunately has a lot of double counting. Example $[e_1, s_1,c_1](extra_1, extra_2, s_2)$ and $[e_1, s_2, c_1](extra_1, extra_2, s_1)$ would be counted at least twice.

Comment: In any case, it is worth doing the inclusion-exclusion calculation as it is straight forward and would quickly provide the answer.  Then you can compare what other methods yield to that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your calculation.  Fist, there is no reason to divide by $3!$.   When you choose an English course, a Chinese course, and a Spanish course, the order matters.  You haven't counted anything $6$ times.  Second you have some double counting.  Choosing English 1 and one of the first three courses, and then choosing English 2 as one of the remaining three course is the same as choosing English 2 as one of the first three, and then choosing English 1 as one of the last three.

If you want to do this without inclusion-exclusion (although that's the method I would recommend) note that you can either choose two courses in each language in $${3\choose2}{6\choose2}{6\choose2}$$ ways, or choose two English courses, one in one of the other languages and three of the third in $$2{3\choose2}{6\choose1}{6\choose3}$$ ways, or one English course, two in one of the otherLanguages and three of the third in $$2{3\choose1}{6\choose2}{6\choose3}$$ ways or one English course, one in one of the other languages and four of the third in $$2{3\choose1}{6\choose1}{6\choose4}$$ ways or three English courses, two in one of the other languages and one of the third in $$2{3\choose3}{6\choose2}{6\choose1}$$ ways, if I haven't missed any.

Answer (score 1):

The generating function for the number of $k$ courses such that there at least one course from each category is the following:
$$\Bigg( \binom{3}{1}x + \binom{3}{2}x^2 + \binom{3}{3}x^3 \Bigg) \Bigg(\binom{6}{1}x + \binom{6}{2}x^2 + \binom{6}{3}x^3 + \binom{6}{4}x^4 +\binom{6}{5}x^5 + \binom{6}{6}x^6 \Bigg)^2$$

Thus the number of ways to choose $6$ courses with at least one from each category is the coefficient of $x^6$ in the generating function above.